# Find a directory in shared library search path

Tags: c, linux, search-path

I want dlopen() every shared library in a specific directory. In order to do that,
what is the cleanest way to retrieve linux's library search path. Or Is there a quicker way of find a specific directory in that path ?
posix would be better.

Comment: Do you mean you want to `dlopen` every library in every directory of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: nope, I mean to dlopen every library in a specific sub-directory of every directory of what replaces LD_LIBRARY_PATH in Linux.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

POSIX does not support a mechanism to find out the directories on the shared library search path (it does not mandate `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, for example), so any solution is inherently somewhat platform specific.

Linux presents some problems because the values to be used could be based on the contents of `/etc/ld.so.conf` as well as any runtime value in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable; other systems present comparable problems.  The default locations also vary by system - with `/lib` and `/usr/lib` being usual for 32-bit Linux machines but `/lib64` and `/usr/lib64` being used on at least some 64-bit machines.  However, other platforms use other locations for 64-bit software.  For example, Solaris uses `/lib/sparcv9` and `/usr/lib/sparcv9`, for example (though the docs mention `/lib/64` and `/usr/lib/64`, they're symlinks to the `sparcv9` directories).  Solaris also has environment variables `LD_LIBRARY_PATH_64` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH_32`.  HP-UX and AIX traditionally use other variables than `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` -- `SHLIB_PATH` and `LIBPATH`, IIRC -- though I believe AIX now uses `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` too.  And, on Solaris, the tool for configuring shared libraries is 'crle' (configure runtime linking environment) and the analog of `/etc/ld.so.conf` is either `/var/ld/ld.config` or `/var/ld/64/ld.config`.  Also, of course, the extensions on shared libraries varies (`.so`, `.sl`, `.dylib`, `.bundle`, etc).

So, your solution will be platform-specific.  You will need to decide on the the default locations, the environment variables to read, and the configuration file to read, and the relevant file extension.  Given those, then it is mainly a SMOP - Simple Matter Of Programming:

- For each directory named by any of the sources:

  - Open the relevant sub-directory (`opendir()`)

    - Read each file name (`readdir()`) in turn
    - Use `dlopen()` on the path of the relevant files.
    - Do whatever analysis is relevant to you.
    - Use `dlclose()`
  - Use `closedir()`

See also the notes in the comment below...the complete topic is modestly fraught with variations from platform to platform.

Comment: Some additional info, feel free to incorporate into answer: LD_PRELOAD can also specify specific libraries that should be used instead of the ones found in the search path, and the app binary and any libs that are opened may have an RPATH baked into them that specifies additional directories to look at. You can see what's in the RPATH of a app/lib on Linux with "objdump -p my_app_or_lib | grep RPATH". If you're not familiar with RPATH, adding "-R/foo" to your LDFLAGS when linking will cause the linker to insert /foo into your binary such that the dynamic linker will look in /foo for libraries.

Comment: Great answer, thanks Jonathan. It's really strange though that something that simple should be as complicated as this

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's possible to do that and be portable. Since this question is about Linux, portability may not be of paramount importance. Then I do not understand the POSIX constraint. Could you clarify?

You'll probably have to either implement the search functionality detailed in `man 8 ld.so`, which includes scanning /etc/ld.so.conf in addition to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, or make `/lib/ld.so` do what you want for you and parse the output. A not-exactly-pretty command line for that could be:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=THISLIBRARYSODOESNOTEXIST
strace -s 4096 /bin/true 2>&1 | sed -n 's/^open("\([^"]*\)\/THISLIBRARYSODOESNOTEXIST".*$/\1\/YOURSUBDIRHERE/gp'
unset LD_PRELOAD
```

You can then enumerate files with the POSIX calls `opendir(3)` and `readdir(3)`.