# Why am I getting segfault with loading objects from shared library?

Tags: c, error-handling, segmentation-fault, shared-libraries, dlopen

Having this files:

*plusone.c*

```
int op(int i){ return i+1; }
```

*main.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if (argc<3){
        printf("usage %s <library> <number>\n",argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    char *lname = argv[1];
    int num = atoi(argv[2]);
    void *handle = dlopen(lname, RTLD_LAZY);
    if(!handle)
        perror("dlopen");

    int (*opp)(int);
    opp=dlsym(handle, "op");
    if(!opp)
        perror("dlsym");

    printf("number before:%i\nnumber after:%i\n",num,opp(num)); 
    dlclose(handle);
}
```

Compiled as:

```
$cc -fPIC -shared -o plusone.so -ldl plusone.c
$cc -o main.exe -ldl -Wpedantic main.c
warning: ISO C forbids assignment between function pointer and ‘void *’ [-Wpedantic]
$ls
main.c main.exe plusone.so main.exe
$main.exe
usage main.exe <library> <number>
$main plusone.so 1
dlopen: Success
dlsym: Success
Segmentation fault
```

Why is segfault?

As could be seen from the bash output, both the `dlopen` and `dlsym` give success (but they should not even output, otherwise that mean, the condition was true, and the returned values from those functions was NULL? - as from condition). But even of the "success" the `perror` returned, I cannot reproduce the segfault, since do not know where is the bug.

Comment: The code you show doesn't print "Success" anywhere, so it's not the [mcve] you use to capture the output. Please make sure that the code you show is the one you actually run.

Comment: And have you tried to build both the library and executable with debug information (adding the `-g` flag) and then run in a debugger to catch the crash? When in your code does it happen? What are the values of all involved variables at that point? I also suggest you enable verbose warnings when building (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`) and treat all warnings as errors that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude what? It does output, you can copy/paste the main.c. Compiled with `-ldl` and runit. The are twp perrors, which gets hit and output (see man perror). I have just copied it a compile as `cc -ldl foo.c; ./a.out` and that was exactly the output

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, after adding the warning flags, only one appeared: `warning: ISO C forbids assignment between function pointer and ‘void *’ [-Wpedantic]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Why is segfault?*

Most likely because `opp` equals `NULL` the moment `opp(num)` is trying to be called.

You do not handle errors correctly for the calls to `dlopen()` and `dlysym()`, although the code tests the results it does not take the correct actions on failure of those two functions.

This code

```
  void *handle = dlopen(lname, RTLD_LAZY);
  if(!handle)
    perror("dlopen");
```

correctly branches on `dlopen()` returning `NULL` which indicated an error, but then the code takes the wrong actions.

[`dlopen()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlopen.html) does **not** set `errno`, so using [`perror()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/perror.html) to log an error makes no sense, as `perror()` relies on `errno` indicating an error, which is does not. So on failure of `dlopen()` you see `perror()` printing

```
dlopen: Success
```

which is misleading and contractionary to the fact that `perror()` was called at all, which in fact only happened if `dlopen()` returned `NULL`, indicating a failure. If `dlopen()` would have succeeded, `perror()` would not have been called at all and nothing would have been printed.

The same mistake appears with the call to [`dlsym()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlsym.html).

To retrieve error info on failure of a member of the `dl*()` family of functions use [`dlerror()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlerror.html).

For an example on how to correctly and completely implement error handling see below:

```
  void *handle = dlopen(...);
  if (!handle)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "dlopen: %s\n", dlerror());
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); /* Or do what ever to avoid using the value of handle. */
  }
#ifdef DEBUG
  else
  {
    fputs("dlopen: Success\n", stderr);
  }
#endif
```

The same approach should be taken to handle the outcome of `dlsym()`.

---

Aside of all this and unrelated to the observed behaviour the code misses to call [`dlclose()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2013edition/functions/dlclose.html) when done with using a valid `handle`.

Comment: @autistic456. `main plusone.so 1` -> `main ./plusone.so 1`

Comment: @stef1611, what do you mean, by explicitly making the libraru from current dir? Why cannot I call plusone.so without `./` prefix?

Comment: @autistic456. I do not really know. I open a question.

Comment: @Stef1611 then give me a link, because it interest me as well. I know linker does not look in the current directory but to some others dirs (some are defaults) for dynamic libraries, so if I prefix it with `./` then I am explicitly telling linker to in the current dir for the library (where it indeed is), so you are right, but does not know why are defaults directories linker looks into. Because there seems that dynamic libraries have special treatment and I do not know how. So give me link once you open question

Comment: @autistic456. An interesting link : https://stackoverflow.com/q/4213857/7462275