# How to display all files in directory of which name is specified by the user as "ls dir_name" in Linux C program

Tags: c, linux

I am writing a simple terminal in C programming in which I want to displays all the files present in a directory the format will be as "ls dir_name". E.g if I enter the command like "ls Download" it will display all the files in downloads directory. I have tried to search it on different platforms but have not found anything helpful regarding this. Here is a sample code I tried but it is displaying only those files which is in pwd.

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    d = opendir(".");
    if (d)
    {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
        }
        closedir(d);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages, please pick one

Comment: Updated thanks for pointing it out @idclev463035818

Comment: Instead of `d = opendir(".");`, which opens the PWD, you should probably call `opendir` on the path to the directory for which you want a listing.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Does your code not work as intended?  If not, could you describe what is happening?

Comment: @DanielWalker I want to give file name on my own but this code is giving result just like simple ls command did i.e giving all files of present working directory. But I want it to work as the user should give the directory name like ls dir_name and then it will display all the files present in thar directory.

Comment: @rici I cannot give the path I just have to give the dir_name. The thing you are talking is not needed here as I am building basic bash like thing.

Comment: @LeoCoder: In this case, the directory name you want to use *is* a path. It's a relative path, but it is still a path. `.` is also a path. `.` is the path to the current working directory. `opendir` will open the directory you tell it to open, but it won't try to read your mind to guess that you wanted to open a different directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a program you can use as starting point.

It takes an optional directory name as argument which can be relative to the current directory or a full path name.

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *dir_name;
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;

    if (argc == 0)
      return 1;
    if (argc == 1)
      dir_name = ".";   
    if (argc == 2)
      dir_name = argv[1];
    if (argc > 2)
    {
      printf("usage: myls [directory]\n");
      return 1;
    }

    d = opendir(dir_name);
    if (d)
    {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
        }
        closedir(d);
    }
    else
    {
      printf("directory %s not found\n", dir_name);
      return 1;
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use [`scandir()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scandir.3.html).

Consider the following example:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int default_filter(const struct dirent *ent)
{
    /* Keep only entries that do not begin with a '.'. */
    return (ent->d_name[0] != '.');
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int  arg;

    /* Use user's locale rules (for alphasort). */
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    /* Usage */
    if (argc < 2 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        const char *this = (argc > 0) ? argv[0] : "(this)";
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", this);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s DIR [ DIR ... ]\n", this);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (arg = 1; arg < argc; arg++) {
        struct dirent **list = NULL;
        int             i, count;

        count = scandir(argv[arg], &list, default_filter, alphasort);
        if (count == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv[arg], strerror(errno));
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            printf("%s\n", list[i]->d_name);
        }
        fflush(stdout);

        free(list);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The `default_filter()` is a directory entry filter, that skips (by returning zero) for those that start with a `.`, and keeps all others (by returning nonzero).

The `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` tells the C library to use the rules for users current locale for character classes, sorting and so on.

The `count = scandir(argv[arg], &list, default_filter, alphasort)` does the directory scanning, saving the entries (not filtered out), sorted by `alphasort()`, into `list`, a dynamically allocated array of pointers to dirent structures.  (That's why we need to provide a pointer to `list`: so that scandir can allocate a suitably sized array.) If it returns `-1`, an error occurred with `errno` describing the exact error.  Otherwise, `list[i]->d_name` contains the file name of the `i`'th entry, `i` ranging from `0` to `count-1`, inclusive.

After the entries are no longer needed, a `free(list)` frees it from memory.

This is the right way to do it, as this is how the standard utilities do it, too.

The example above even works in other POSIX-y OSes, not just Linux: Mac OS, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, and so on.

The reason you should **not** use opendir()/readdir()/closedir() is that scandir() (and `nftw()` and `glob()`) should handle correctly the cases where files and directories are moved while they are being listed/scanned/globbed/traversed, but almost no programmer does that correctly with opendir()/readdir()/closedir() because it is too much work.

Besides, why invent your own version, when there is better, [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) version already available?